# How to specify the root of the project to call JS functions from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web

In my project i have such structure:

```
/simpleTest
  /src
    /demo.js

  /test
    /subfolder
      /index.html
```

What i need is to include my **demo.js** file into my **index.html**, to be able to call js functions from my html.

Here is what i have in my html:

```
<head>
  <title>Test case</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/simpleTest/src/demo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="callTest()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Here is my simple javascript file:

```
function callTest(){
    alert("!");
}
```

If i leave it like this - nothing happens, when i press "Click" button. I also have tried to change src path to *"../simpleTest/src/demo.js"*, *"./simpleTest/src/demo.js"*, *"simpleTest/src/demo.js"*, *"../src/demo.js", "./src/demo.js"*, *"src/demo.js"*, but it only works with absolute path: *"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\simpleTest\src\demo.js"* which is not applicable for any real project.

Also, if i change src path to *"demo.js"* and a structure to

```
/simpleTest
  /demo.js
  /index.html
```

it works, as well as changing path to *"../src/demo.js"* and structure to

```
/simpleTest
  /src
    /demo.js

  /test
    /index.html
```

helps. But both of this desidions are not for me (i have a certain purposes to have a structure, which i've mentioned at the beginning of the post).

So, please, tell me how can i specify the root of my project for the structure a want, to fit the src path to the first one structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need such a folder structure, use this as a path:

```
../../src/demo.js
```

With each `..` you basically go one level up inside your structure. You should do this, until you reach a folder, from which you can access the subfolders leading to your file.

<sup>Do you really need such a deeply nested folder structure? Generally, I advice to use a rather flat folder structure. There are reasons to use more nesting, but I can't see any of them here.</sup>

Comment: So, you mean there is no way to specify just a root folder, without mentioning every parent node in a tree? So that if my structure has more then 3 folders, i don't want to type them all like this ../../../../...  And what is worse - if a structure will change - with this one decision i'll have to fix all paths, and i don't like it.

Comment: PS: i really can't change my folder structure: it is not a pure web projects, it is just a part of some other "system", that is why i have such deep nesting (as a requirements of that "system"). And what i'm doing is just trying to use unit testing frameworks for all my JS files, that why i have html file (so it is like a temporary object in my project).

Comment: @AgafonovaVictoria One different approach may be to use a loader-script like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/). In the respective settings you can add a base path from which to load. Require.js in particular, however, expects your JavaScript files to follow AMD pattern, but there might be similar libraries, which do not.